# Why is empty unordered_map.find not returning end()?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, stdstring

I am trying to test if a entry in a unordered_map already exists with a given key. I am using the find() function to return a iterator. The problem is that whether the unordered_map is empty (or not) it returns a 'empty' object when there is no entry with the given key, like this -

```cpp
it = (<Error reading characters of string.>, -842150451)
```

I have tried creating an empty project solution and putting in a minimal example. It still returns the same 'empty' object for find(). I have even tried changing the type of key from std::string to int with the same results.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string key = "test";
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> myMap;
    myMap["abc"] = 5;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int>::iterator it = myMap.find(key);
}
```

I am expecting find() to return 'end' when there is no entry with the given key, but the output is some sort of 'empty' object.

Comment: How are you determining if `it` is the end iterator or not? An end interator won't have a sensible key or value.

Comment: @Stuart Where is there the statement that outputs anything? It is undefined behavior to use the iterator returned by the function end.

Comment: The end iterator doesn’t necessarily contain anything sensible, since you’re not allowed to look inside it. Conversely, you can’t look inside an iterator to determine whether it is an end iterator.

Comment: Whatever tool produced the `it = (<Error reading characters of string.>, -842150451)` string, what does it produce for what `end()` returns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare the iterator to the end of your list, e.g.

```
  if (it == myMap.end()) {
    std::cout << "didn't find" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "found " << it->second << std::endl;
  }
```